# Cell content validation only

Tags: excel, vba

I like to validate cell content on Non pritables, carriage returns, spaces and not wanted symbols.  In use this if statement in my code:

```
If CellChck.Text Like "*[^-_,A-Z-0-9]*" Then
```

It is almost perfect only disadvantage is that 4 symbols are not catched: *()@

Who can give me the proper code?

This is my code:

```
Dim RangeToCheck As Range
Dim CellChck As Range

For Each CellCheck In RangeToCheck
If Len(CellCheck.Text) > 0 Then
If CellCheck.Text Like "*[^-_,A-Z-0-9]*" Then   
CellCheck.Font.Color = vbRed
CellCheck.Font.Bold = True        
Else:   CellCheck.Font.Color = vbBlack
CellCheck.Font.Bold = False
End If
End If
Next CellCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating custom function to validate that instead of using `Like` operator:

```
Function ContainsSpecialChar(stringToProcess As String) As Boolean

ContainsSpecialChar = False
Dim specialChars As Variant: specialChars = Array("^", "_", " ", ")", "(", "*", "@", _
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", _
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")

For Each char In specialChars
    If InStr(1, stringToProcess, char) > 0 Then
        ContainsSpecialChar = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next char

End Function
```

And in your `If` condition you could write: `If ContainsSpecialChar(CellCheck.Text) Then`

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not work now all gets selected when I use your string with my variable:   If CellChck.Text Like "*[^-_,A-Z-0-9)(*@]*" Then

Comment: Thank you Michal, can you give me an solution how I can call this function that I inserted as a new module? I now get an error when I use the If condition you advised:  If ContainsSpecialChar(CellCheck.Text) Then    -->  Compile error Expected variable or procedure not module

Comment: @vinmeg Function is a function and has to be declared as one, not as module or anything else.

Comment: Dear Michal,  If I add the function and run this over some test cell values entered all text is updated to red and bold even the correct cell values. In order you understand what I did I will paste the complete code I run now. Maybe you can test it on your end.

Comment: Function ValidateCellContent()

Comment: For Each CellCheck In RangeToCheck
If Len(CellCheck.Text) > 0 Then
 If ContainsSpecialChar(CellCheck.Text) = True Then
        CellCheck.Font.Color = vbRed
        CellCheck.Font.Bold = True
    Else:   CellCheck.Font.Color = vbBlack
            CellCheck.Font.Bold = False
    End If
End If
Next CellCheck
End Function

Comment: Function ContainsSpecialChar(stringToProcess As String) As Boolean
ContainsSpecialChar = False
Dim specialChars As Variant: specialChars = Array _
        ("^", "_", " ", ")", "(", "*", "@", _
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", _
        "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", _
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
For Each char In specialChars
    If InStr(1, stringToProcess, char) > 0 Then
        ContainsSpecialChar = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next char
End Function

Comment: Had o paste it into two comments due to max characters